# Series representation of $1/\pi\int_0^\pi e^{\lambda \cos(t)}\cos(nt)dt$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Are there representations of $a_n=1/\pi\int_0^\pi e^{\lambda \cos(t)}\cos(nt)dt,~n\in\mathbb{N},~\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ as a series?

These $a_n$ are the coefficients of the Laurent series $a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n(z^n+z^{-n})$ of $\exp(\frac{\lambda}{2}(z+z^{-1}))$.

Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%E2%80%93Anger_expansion

Comment: See my remark to your previous problem. (It's the same idea as Jack's, though.)

Comment: Thanks to you two! I have read your links but how can I get such a representation without knowing facts about this bessel functions?